# Bootstrap grid or table for a responsive website?

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am looking to convert a C# ASP.NET MVC 3 web application to a MVC 5. During this process I wish to create a more responsive table through the use of bootstrap. Would it be better to use the bootstrap grid system with using  tags or would it be better to utilize a table? Is there a method to increase the number of columns in the grid system to a number greater than 12?

Note:
The new application will utilize bootstrap 3.2.0, jquery 1.11.1, mvc 5.2.0n razor 3.2.0.
The application must work correctly on IE8 (staying on jquery 1.X branch for this reason).

Below is an example table from the current application that I am unsure how to format to have a similar look in a responsive interface.

```
<table class="Assignmenttable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="td">
            <th id="Assignment_Title" colspan="4" style="width:20%"> </th>
            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
            </th>
            <th id="Assignment_Title" colspan="9" style="width:30%"> First</th>
            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
            </th>
            <th id="Assignment_Title" colspan="9" style=" width:30%"> Second</th>
            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
            </th>
            <th id="Assignment_Title" colspan="4" style="width:11%"> Complete</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="td">
            <th rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="font-size: medium">Assignment</th>
            <th colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="font-size: medium; min-width:12%">Woot</th>

            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1" rowspan="1">

            </th>
            <th colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="font-size: medium; min-width:12%">Task 1</th>
            <th colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="font-size: medium; min-width:12%">Task 2</th>
            <th colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="font-size: medium; min-width:12%">Task 3</th>

            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1" rowspan="1">

            </th>
            <th colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="font-size: medium; min-width:12%">Task 4</th>
            <th colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="font-size: medium; min-width:12%">Task 5</th>
            <th colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="font-size: medium; min-width:12%">Task 6</th>

            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1" rowspan="1">

            </th>
            <th colspan="4" rowspan="2" style="font-size: medium; min-width:12%">Task 7</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="td">
            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1">
            </th>
            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1">
            </th>
            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1">
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="td">
            <th></th>
            <th id="topBarDates">PL</th>
            <th id="topBarDates">LE</th>
            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></th>
            <th></th>
            <th id="topBarDates">PL</th>
            <th id="topBarDates">LE</th>
            <th></th>
            <th id="topBarDates">PL</th>
            <th id="topBarDates">LE</th>
            <th></th>
            <th id="topBarDates">PL</th>
            <th id="topBarDates">LE</th>
            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></th>
            <th></th>
            <th id="topBarDates">PL</th>
            <th id="topBarDates">LE</th>
            <th></th>
            <th id="topBarDates">PL</th>
            <th id="topBarDates">LE</th>
            <th></th>
            <th id="topBarDates">PL</th>
            <th id="topBarDates">LE</th>
            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></th>

            <th> P1 </th>
            <th colspan=""> P2</th>
            <th id="topBarDates">PL</th>
            <th id="topBarDates">LE</th>
        </tr>


        <!-- This row is for each assignment entry-->
        <tr class="td" style="height: 60px; max-height: 100px">

            <td id="td" class="td" style="width: 350px">
                Project 2
            </td>


            <td id="LongDelay" align="center">
                <input id="item_Shipped" name="item.task1" onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="item.task1" type="hidden" value="false">
            </td>
            <td id="ProjectDate">11-Apr-13</td>
            <td id="ProjectDate">17-Aug-13</td>

            <td id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1"></td>


            <td id="LongDelay" align="center">
                <input checked="checked" id="item_taskComplete" name="item.taskComplete" onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="item.taskComplete" type="hidden" value="false">
            </td>
            <td id="ProjectDate">
                05-Apr-14
            </td>
            <td id="ProjectDate">
                04-Aug-14
            </td>


            <td id="LongDelay" align="center">
                <input id="item_taskComplete" name="item.task" onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="item.task" type="hidden" value="false">
            </td>
            <td  id="ProjectDate">18-Apr-14</td>
            <td  id="ProjectDate">06-Aug-14</td>


            <td id="LongDelay" align="center">
                <input checked="checked" id="item_taskComplete" name="item.taskComplete" onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="item.taskComplete" type="hidden" value="false">
            </td>
            <td id="ProjectDate">
                21-Feb-14
            </td>
            <td id="ProjectDate">
                15-Apr-14
            </td>

            <td id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1"></td>


            <td id="SlightDelay" align="center">
                <input checked="checked" id="item_taskComplete" name="item.taskComplete" onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="item.taskComplete" type="hidden" value="false">
            </td>
            <td title="" id="ProjectDate">28-Mar-14</td>
            <td title="" id="ProjectDate">11-Apr-14</td>


            <td id="LongDelay" align="center">
                <input id="item_task6" name="item.task6" onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="item.task6" type="hidden" value="false">
            </td>
            <td title="" id="ProjectDate">15-Apr-14</td>
            <td title="" id="ProjectDate">28-Aug-14</td>

            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td id="blank" class="blank" colspan="1"></td>



            <td id="LongDelay" align="center">
                <input id="item_taskAccepted" name="item.taskAccepted" onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="item.taskAccepted" type="hidden" value="false">
            </td>
            <td id="LongDelay" align="center">
                <input id="item_task2Accepted" name="item.task2Accepted" onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="item.task2Accepted" type="hidden" value="false">
            </td>
            <td id="ProjectDate">30-Apr-14  </td>
            <td id="ProjectDate">07-Aug-14</td>


        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 4px">
            <th id="blank" class="blank" colspan="29"></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: "Is there a method to increase the number of columns in the grid system to a number greater than 12?" Yes. That number is a variable in the Less source code. Simply change the value and recompile the Less files to CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into [Bootstrap Tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables).

Between choosing to use Tables or Grid, it entirely depends on what you're trying to show. Without proper examples, it's hard to really suggest which one is better to use.

If you want use Bootstrap's table for your code, it's as easy as just putting a `.table` class for your `<table>` element. Then, for it to properly scale you need to remove the inline styles attached to your `<th>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` elements. Even the `colspans`.

Comment: I created an example of what the current view looks with out the responsive interface which includes the styles used in the above example. Let me know what you think. http://jsfiddle.net/tester123/muofm3zb/